# Solving a puzzle from http get Java

Tags: java

I am currently doing a group project where we get a "message of the day" which is cryptic and has to be solved. I must shift the first character forward one character and the second character back one character, and then continue this process for all characters. I have included my code in how I thought I could achieve this but am struggling with the different types.

Am I going about this the right way? After converting the string builder to an int can I convert it back?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MOTD {

```
static StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {

          URL url = new URL();
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             result.append(line);
          }
          rd.close();
          return result.toString();
       }

   public StringBuilder solvePuzzle(StringBuilder newResult) {


       char letterOne = newResult.charAt(0);
       char letterTwo = newResult.charAt(1);
       char letterThree = newResult.charAt(2);
       char letterFour = newResult.charAt(3);
       char letterFive = newResult.charAt(4);
       char letterSix = newResult.charAt(5);
       char letterSeven = newResult.charAt(6);

       letterOne++;
       letterTwo--;
       letterThree--;
       letterFour++;
       letterFive--;
       letterSix++;
       letterSeven--;

       String letter1 = new StringBuilder().append(letterOne).toString();
       String letter2 = new StringBuilder().append(letterTwo).toString();
       String letter3 = new StringBuilder().append(letterThree).toString();
       String letter4 = new StringBuilder().append(letterFour).toString();
       String letter5 = new StringBuilder().append(letterFive).toString();
       String letter6 = new StringBuilder().append(letterSix).toString();
       String letter7 = new StringBuilder().append(letterSeven).toString();


       letter1.toString();
       letter2.toString();
       letter3.toString();
       letter4.toString();
       letter5.toString();
       letter6.toString();
       letter7.toString();

       newResult = letterOne + letterTwo + letterThree + letterFour +
               letterFive + letterSix + letterSeven;       

       return newResult;   

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       System.out.println(getHTML("http://cswebcat.swan.ac.uk/puzzle"));
       System.out.println("This is the puzzle: " + result);
       System.out.println("This is the solved puzzle: " + result.solvePuzzle());


   }
```

}

Comment: *"Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!"* There doesn't seem to be any specific question here.

Comment: So you want a word like "computer" to end up like "ocpmture"? (swapping 1 and 2, 3 and 4, etc)

Comment: No sorry the first letter shifts one place in the alphabet, the second shifts back one place in the alphabet and so on, so CAT would become DZU, the website changes the word length so I think I need a loop instead of fixed variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting or adding from/to a char does not do what you're expecting. For example:

```
char a = 'a';
a--; // This will result in the character '`' (not 'z')

char z = 'z';
z++; // This will result in the character '{' (not 'a')
```

(This will work for the other letters in the alphabet)

For this you will need a method like this:

```
public char shift(char c, final int shift) {
    // Use -1 for subtracting
    if(shift == -1) {

        // Manually shift a to z when subtracting
        if(c == 'a') {
            return 'z';
        }

        // Otherwise just return the subtracted value
        return --c;
    }

    // Use 1 for adding
    if(shift == 1) {

        // Manually shift z to a when adding
        if(c == 'z') {
            return 'a';
        }

        // Otherwise just return the added value
        return ++c;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Now you can use this method to solve the puzzle.

```
public String solve(final String input) {

    // Get all individual characters from the input string
    char[] chars = new char[input.length()];
    input.getChars(0, input.length(), chars, 0);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop through each character
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

        // If the character is the 1st, 3rd, 5th and so on
        // (i = 0 or i = 2 or i = 4 ...)
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            // Shift one forward
            result.append(shift(chars[i], 1));

        // If the character is the 2nd, 4th, 6th and so on
        // (i = 1 or i = 3 or i = 5 ...)
        } else {
            // Shift one back
            result.append(shift(chars[i], -1));
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

I hope this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much this was extremely helpful. Thanks for commenting too so I could understand what you were doing